# What is the use of a constant union object?

Tags: c++, c, constants, unions

If I make a const union object (e.g in code below ), then no member assignment can be done in that. So is there any use of making a const union object, in any case ?

```
union un
{
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
};
const union un a; 
/// ! a.i = 10; error.
```

Comment: In `c` it is not uncommon to interpret a union through a different member to that which was most recently set. And of course, it could be `const volatile` - i.e. we won't change it, but someone else might, and we need to be able to see that.

Comment: Not if the whole damn union is `const`.

Comment: @Xeo, it wouldn't compile without the "union" part when I tested with gcc.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: Yeah, I thought the question was only tagged C++ at first, but it's also C, so the `union` "elaborate type specifier" makes it portable. I rollback'd my rollback. :P

Comment: @BoBTFish it's Undefined Behavior. The fact that most of the time it just happens to work does not make it less UB. The fact that "it is not uncommon" does not make it less UB.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can still initialize the union as follows:

```
const union un a = { .i = 100 };
```

then use it in your code.

Comment: In C, that is. In C++, I think you could write a constructor and such stuff.

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it by 35 seconds. :-)

Comment: This is what I didn't know. This way any union member can be initialized !

Answer (score 16):

You can still assign it at declaration, for instance like this:

```
const union un a = {0};
```

Update: that notation sets the *first* of the union members.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, all members, to zero.

Comment: Yeah, but that can only be done to assign the first member only ( or to set all to zero, as u mentioned) !

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The first member.  Formally, if you have `union un { short s; double d; }; union un a = {};`, the contents of `d` are undefined (and if `a` is const, there's no way you could legally access them anyway).

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant That's wrong (unless they've changed something in the last version of the C standard).  In C90, union initialization is always the first member.  In C99, there's an extended syntax (not present in C++) to initialize a different member, but there is still only one member which is initialized.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, sorry I was in a hurry. Yes, it's the first one. I was thinking about structs, where {0} is (nonstandard?) shorthand for setting all members.

Comment: C11 6.7.9/17 "Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union."

Comment: C11 6.7.9/21 "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate..." /--/  "...the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: @JamesKanze So as far as I can tell from the standard, `un a = {0};` means: set the first union member to zero, and set the rest of the union members as if they were statics, ie set them to zero/NULL as well.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think that's a reasonable interpretation.  Consider what it would means for `un a { 42 };`.  Initialization of the first element (a short in my example) to `42`, then the next to 0 would 1) overwrite the explicit initialization, and 2) mean that your first access would have to be the last element declared.

Comment: @Lundin (It's an interesting point, however.  Perhaps a DR is in order.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I think in practice, it will work like "set everything to zero, then set the first member to 42".

Comment: @Lundin That may be what implementations are doing, but there's no way I can read the statement you quoted to mean that.

Comment: @JamesKanze, why not?  The standard usually specifies the end result, not the exact order. It's not concerned with *how* the union is stored in memory. I may be dense, but Lundins argument is sound to me.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant His quote (which admittedly isn't exact, and I don't have the exact wording handy) says "set the first union member to [the value given], and set the rest of the union members as if they were static".  If you write `un a { 42 };`, with my definition of `un`, this means setting `s` to 42, and then setting `d` to `0.0`.  Since the text was written for `struct`, it doesn't mention order, but at the very least, setting them in the order would be legal.  And if you set `d` to 0, then `s` will not be 42.

Comment: @JamesKanze, OK, then it gets kind of muddy.

Comment: @JamesKanze, still, I think standards are like laws. In the corner causes, you have to apply interpretetion. (No pun intended.) And then hope for the next revision to be more exact.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant The problem is: given the exact wording you quote, there is no possible interpretation that is acceptable.  Elsewhere, on the other hand, there is wording which says that the initializer of a union applies to the first member.  Which suggests that that statement should have precedence.  But IMHO, a DR is in order---and **if** all, or even most, actual implementations do set everything to 0, it would seem reasonable to standardize that behavior.